# Data structure with multiple keys in python

Tags: python, data-structures

I have a timeseries based data set with multiple keys - up to 5 (e.g.LocationCategory, SizeCategory, ClimateCategory) and corresponding values - up to 10 (e.g.Temperature, Humidity, SunlightHoursperDay).

The total raw data corresponds to around 1 GB. For my analysis I quickly want to query the values based on the different keys (sometimes only by one, sometimes by multiple). I know databases are the ideal situation for this, however I want to share this data and python script with people who might not be connected to a network. Hence, I would like to have a local implementation of the data structure in python.

```
WeatherDataPointCollection[Location]
WeatherDataPointCollection[Location, Size, Climate]
```

A datapoint would look something like:

```
class WeatherDataPoint: 
   ''' should have a unique key set of Location, Size, Climate '''
   Temperature = 12
   Humidity = 42
   Sunlight = 0.49
```

I need help bringing the two things together, i.e. getting all WeatherDataPoints that match the above key(s) specifications.

Comment: As you know, database is the best solution. How about using `sqlite3`? See: https://docs.python.org/ko/3/library/sqlite3.html

Comment: Yes, that's brilliant. Exactly what I need. Thanks!